# What's the JSON format that Datatables.js uses to request and retrieve data?

Tags: php, json, ajax, datatables, codeigniter-3

I want to implement an Ajax enabled Datatables.js table with PHP and CodeIgniter 3.

What's the JSON format that Datatables.js uses to request and retrieve data? I could not find it in the documentation.

**UPDATE:**
I need pagination for big data. I cannot get all records at once. Then the Ajax requesting format should be something specific.

Comment: Refer this: https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-Datatable---Server-Side-with-Custom-Inline-Editing

or

https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-datatable-client-side-demo-implementation

Comment: are you looking for server side or client side?

Comment: I want to write server side code using PHP based on Datatables request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there, just needs a bit of digging :-)

[This page](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) details the sent parameters and the returned data. The DataTable sends some data when using server-side processing and expects the returned data to be in a specific format - both of which are detailed in that page far better than I can here.

Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

DataTables has the ability to read data from virtually any JSON data source that can be obtained by Ajax. https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax

Comment: I need pagination. for big data. then the ajax format is important